# How can i use notification & alert in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, notifications, alert

```swift
    @IBAction func tapDeleteButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title:"Are you sure?",message: "Do you really want to delete?",preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                    let cancle = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(cancle)
                    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        let delete = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive){(_) in
            let uuidString = self.diary?.uuidString
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("deleteDiary"), object: uuidString, userInfo: nil)
        }
                    alert.addAction(delete)
                    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

hello.
I'm studying swift while making a diary app.

But I'm stuck creating a delete button for a cell.

I get an error when I tap delete in alert.

How can I handle delete with notification and alert in there??

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally a view controller <UIAlertController: 0x7ff2b3025e00> that is already being presented by <UITabBarController: 0x7ff2b4027a00>.' The app ends with this error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you are trying to display another `UIAlertController` on the currently presented `UIAlertController`.

You are presenting your `UIAlertController` twice.

Remove the line `present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)` under `let alert = ...`.

Comment: Thanks my friend. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because, You have presented the alert twice

Try this:

```
@IBAction func tapDeleteButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
let alert = UIAlertController(title:"Are you sure?",message: "Do you really want to delete?",preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

let cancle = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
let delete = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive){(_) in
    let uuidString = self.diary?.uuidString
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("deleteDiary"), object: uuidString, userInfo: nil)
}

alert.addAction(cancle)
alert.addAction(delete)
present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

Comment: Thanks my friend. The problem is solved.